# Is write system call to a file reduce the memory write cycle how to handle

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, embedded, embedded-linux

I have to read/write a single file multiple times in a day. say may be every second, I have to update the file.

how does this effect the memory(I am using Emmc flash).

since emmc having the defined write cycle over which it will corrupt, please suggest me a best way to handle this.

how about using the **mmap and msync**, is there any possibility to avoid writes..?

if I am using a mmap and writing frequently is it will also write in flash every time I write into the shared mapped memory.?

Comment: If you keep rewriting files over flash storage, you will wear out the flash faster than if you don't. The file system may help protect you by spreading the writes out more evenly. However, the objective should probably be to avoid having to write the entire file so often. There are 1440 minutes in a day; if you need to write the whole file once a minute, and your flash is rated for 100,000 write cycles, then you have the potential to wear out your drives quickly. (There's a factor for "if the file is 1% of the size of the drive, then you can write it 100 times before you go through one cycle).

Comment: See, for instance, results from a Google search on 'ssd wear leveling' such as http://searchsolidstatestorage.techtarget.com/definition/wear-leveling and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling.

Comment: Is there a way to find the embedded linux system shutdown before it gets off.

is there a way to save before the power fail or system shutdown. please give me an example.

Comment: SIGPWR signal?  Otherwise, not sure.

Answer (score 1):

It could depend upon the computer, the file system, the mount options, the kernel (and version).

Perhaps (and actually probably) your file is sitting in the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) and [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)-ing it often does not update the flash memory every time.

You could use something else that a plain file (e.g. a database, or use [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/)) or write your own data daemon to avoid that. If you need that to stay in a file, perhaps consider writing your own [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)

<sup>We cannot help more without actual code and much more details in your question.</sup>